# Is it possible to create an alias for a repository URL in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Is it possible to add an alternative URL for an Azure DevOps repository?

The reason is that we have a project name with a space, e.g. `Stress Some Tools`, which now results in a git URL, which is problematic with many tools:

`https://user@dev.azure.com/myorg-dev/Stress%20Some%20Tools/_git/Good%20Utils`

Hence, an easy solution is getting rid of that `%20` encoded space. [Renaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repo-rename?view=azure-devops) the repository, however, would break existing links for everyone. So I hoped for an alias feature or something similar. The alias has to work for external tools, so ideally azure.com/sometools and azure.com/some%20tools would just point to the same page.

EDIT: If only the *project* name (i.e. Stress Some Tools) is affected, the old and new URL will work after a rename, but **not** for git:

Azure DevOps [rename a *project*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/rename-project?view=azure-devops#results-of-the-rename) docs:

> The URL continues to work for both the new team name and the old team name. This functionality is intended to avoid breaking links.

> If your project uses Git, then your remote references for each repository from the renamed project must be updated.

Comment: I wonder what tools you're having issues with, I've never encountered any.

Comment: [bitbake](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake) in this case

Comment: You might want to figure out the bug and send 'm a patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to rename a git repo without breaking existing users. There is no way to register redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know reasons for this, apart from cost?

Comment: No clue. It's just not a feature. They must have spent their time on other things.

Comment: @Mo_, if you want such a feature which can provide an alternative URL of the Azure Repo, you can submit a feature request on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept jessehouwing's answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).